# insert image in html menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu like this and I want to insert it but social networking buttons that are to the right of all, how could I?

I would add social networking buttons that are images, but I can not insert them, since a div think is inappropriate within a

```
  <div class="botonera"><ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/index.php">INICIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="1.php">CARICATURAS</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.php">DINOSAURIOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">TEMARIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.php">PREGUNTAS</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.php">ACERCA DE</a></li>
    <li><a href="5.php">CONTACTAR</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  #botonera {
        width: 900px;
        height: 21px;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    .texto-botones {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 10px;
        color: #FFF;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .menu,
    .menu ul,
    .menu li,
    .menu a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }

    .menu {
        height: 21px;
        width: 900px;

    }

    .menu li {
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        height: 21px;
    }

    .menu li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 12px;
        margin: 0px 0;
        line-height: 22px;
        text-decoration: none;



        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;

        color: #ffffff;

        -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        text-align: right;
        text-align: right;
        text-align: right;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
    .menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

    .menu li:hover > a {
        color: #FF6C6C;
    }

    .menu ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: -109px;
        left: 0;

        opacity: 0;
        background: #1f2024;

        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

        -webkit-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
        -moz-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
        -o-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
        -ms-transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
        transition: opacity .10s ease .1s;
    }

    .menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

    .menu ul li {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;


    }

    .menu li:hover > ul li {
        height: 36px;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menu ul li a {
        width: 36px;
        padding: 10px 0 1px 10px;
        margin: 0;

        border: none;
        border-bottom: 0px solid #353539;
    }

    .menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

    .menu a.documents { background: url(../img/docs.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
    .menu a.messages { background: url(../img/bubble.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
    .menu a.signout { background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a div after `<ul>` leaving `<ul>` as `float:left;` and new buttons `float:right;`. Make sure both divs are in same container.